How to store this API data in MySQL database localhost
I don't know how to insert this API data in database.
This is my API:
https://api.metalpriceapi.com/v1/latest?api_key=cb15852705e671c76a4dc1ac9789ed2a&base=USD&currencies=XAU,XAG,EUR

This is my code to get/check API data and it is working fine:
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.metalpriceapi.com/v1/latest?api_key=cb15852705e671c76a4dc1ac9789ed2a&base=USD&currencies=XAU,XAG,EUR',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

?>

I was trying to fetch data from this API and want to store this API data in MySQL database in localhost. Basically this is metal price API which shows the rates of metal. I want to store these metal rates in MySQL database in localhost.

fetch-api is a JavaScript function, you seem to be using PHP.

"I want to" is not a question. What specific problem are you having? The API returns JSON, you can use json_decode() to parse it. Then you can loop over the rates element and store them in the database.

problem is :  can you please send me code to store this API data in database.  I need to store this API data in database. please send me code to insert this API data in database.

No, there are many tutorials on writing to databases in PHP, you should learn from them. We'll help you fix your code once you try writing it, we won't write it for you.
